# Best way to build static websites for clients?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have always used html/css/js and converted it to a non-dynamic wordpress theme. Meaning just html/css/js layout where you cannot edit the pages through the back end.

What are some of the best ways to build custom websites for clients, usually just static where it is very SEO friendly?

I am thinking node js with express, what are some other options.

Comment: You may try Hugo. https://gohugo.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused why you would use a dynamic CMS (content management system) like Wordpress when you were only planning on creating a static website. It completely defeats the purpose of it.

However, in answer to your question. The system of HTML/CSS/JS you already use would be the best combination of creating a static site with a high SEO, as long as you maintain the standard of declaring meta tags, optimized links and titles etc.

I would encourage you to develop more in the way of dynamic sites though, as they are more future-proofed and capable of sustaining high SEO scores over time through content change etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of way to have dynamic website.for example you can use most famous programming language like php,asp.net,node.js and others.and seo is not related to programming language and related to meaning concepts of your html structure,your load speed and other things